# insertBefore(int x, Link l) LinkedList Java

Tags: java, linked-list

i want to implement a method which takes as an input an integer and a Link and insert the Link in an LinkedList before the Link in position input integer, what i have achieved:

```
public void insertBefore(int num, String data)
{
    Link current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (current.next != null)
    {
        if(count == num) {
        Link n = new Link(data);
        n.next = current;
        current.next = n.previous;
        }
    }   
    current = current.next;
    count++;

    }
```

However, when i cal the method nothing happens and the Link is not inserted, so any one knows the problem of the method?

Comment: Um, your increment is outside the loop. In fact, this code would infinite loop unless the list only had a head (it would throw a NPE if it was empty and had no head).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, your iteration constructs are outside the iteration mechanism.  Also, you're forgetting to set the next element of current's previous to point to the new link.  Not sure what sort of linked list you're using, but here's an improvement.

```
if (count == num) {
    Link n = new Link(data);
    n.next = current;
    current.previous.next = n;
    n.previous = current.previous;
    current.previous = n;
}
```

In response to the comments below, a more complete improvement based on your code:

```
public void insertBefore(int num, String data)
{
    Link current =  head;
    for (int count = 0; count < num && current.next != null; ++count)
    {
        current = current.next;
    }
    Link n = new Link(data);
    n.next = current;
    if (current.previous != null)
        current.previous.next = n;
    n.previous = current.previous;
    current.previous = n;
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't fix the problem. You haven't changed what `current` is and  the `while` condition is based on `current.next`. It also ignores the fact that by using that as the condition, you can never insert if the list only contains a head.

Comment: That's correct, but I didn't want to touch the looping construct since it was already mentioned.  The loop condition should include a check of count against num, so loop conditions would not be set in the code modifying the list, only in the code iterating it.

Comment: when i tried your solution, i got null pointer exception at     current.previous.next = n;

Comment: This is homework, so I'm trying to give you enough to go on without preventing you from learning from the exercise.  I added in a null check, but you'll want to add in more checks for other conditions (like if the node you're inserting is the head or the tail of the list, etc.  Test the insert with different list sizes and different index parameters, see where it fails, and draw yourself some diagrams to determine why and what additional logic you need to add.